# Does recursion in code still make my code linear to string length

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory

Let's say I have two string `s` and `t` and I want to know if I can get from `s` to `t` via deleting, inserting or replacing a character in `s`. I have the following algorithm:

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isOneEditDistance(String s, String t) {
        return onedistance(s, t, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    private boolean onedistance(String s, String t, int si, int ti, int count) {
        
        if(count > 1) return false;
        while(si < s.length() || ti < t.length()) {
            if(si == s.length()) return onedistance(s, t, si, ti + 1, count + 1);
            if(ti == t.length()) return onedistance(s, t, si + 1, ti, count + 1);
            if(s.charAt(si) == t.charAt(ti)) {
                ti++;
                si++;
            } else {
                return onedistance(s, t, si + 1, ti, count + 1) || 
                    onedistance(s, t, si, ti + 1, count + 1) || 
                    onedistance(s, t, si + 1, ti + 1, count + 1);
            }
        }
        return count == 1;
    }
}
```

Basically, the idea is to keep track of current pointer `si` and `ti` for character we are comparing now for `s` and `t`, if they are the same move both pointer forward, else move either si or ti or both to represent adding, deleting or replacing a char in `s`, we can only do it once, so if `count > 1` we return `false`, at the end we check if count is equal to one to know if edit distance between `s` and `t` is 1.

I am wondering now if my code is `O(m + n)` where `m` and `n` is length of `s` and `t`, because even we have the recursive part, we only do it once and return immediately if `count > 1`;

Comment: What do you mean, you "only do it once"?  If the first recursive call returns false, you call the second one, and if that returns false, you call the third one?  That's up to three recursive calls.  A function call that returns False after an unknown amount of work is still a function call.

Comment: You have answered your own question.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but shouldn't it be `return count <= 1;`?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I'd say, this in fact _is_ O(n), since the threefold branching can be done only once. If it's done a second time, that would immediately return false. The worst case should be two long strings that differ in the first and last chars, where it would split on the first char, then 3x fast-forward the middle part, and fail on the last char in each branch for something like O(3n) which is still O(n).